# Intersect two collections which contain different types

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Suppose I have one collection, call it `ids` it is of type `IEnumerable<string>`, I have a second collection call it `objects` it's of type `MyObject[]`. `MyObject` has a string property called `id`. I would like a LINQ statement that returns all off the objects in the `objects` collection who's `id` matches any value in the `ids` collection. `ids` will be a strict subset of `objects.Select(x => x.id)`. Meaning, for every string in `ids` I know there will be exactly one corresponding `MyObject` in `objects`. Can someone post a pure LINQ solution? I've tried a couple things with no luck. I can come up with an iterative solution easily enough so unless it's impossible to do with only LINQ please don't post any.

Comment: use zip extension method with linq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is pretty straightforward with query syntax.
It would look something like:

```
var a = from o in objects
        join i in ids on o.id equals i
        select o;
```

Comment: @Servy You're right. I've edited my answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: A join... what a novel concept. Seems obvious now but I was in the wrong state of mind, just hung up on the `Intersect` thing.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Eh, it happens. Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes.

Answer (score 8):

"Just" LINQ:

```
var r = obj.Where(o => ids.Any(id => id == o.id));
```

But better, for larger n, with a set:

```
var hs = new HashSet(ids);
var r = obj.Where(o => hs.Contains(o.id));
```

Comment: You can only use `Intersect` if the objects have the same type.  When they have a different type the proper operator is `Join` (or `GroupJoin`, possibly, depending on the data).  `Intersect` is logically a special case of `Join` where the types of the objects are the same, and they are their own key.  Neither of those special cases apply here, which is why you need the more general `Join`.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I was having misgivings about that (now removed) last bit. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: +1 for working answer though a I should certainly be using a `Join`

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I don't know about "certainly". This is the approach I usually use when using Linq2Objects - but it's definitely not the only (or best everywhere) way.

Comment: @user2246674 certainly might be an overstatement. If I were thinking about it more like SQL `Join` would be the obvious choice. When I use LINQ to Objects I tend to approach it more like I would iteration.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a list of MyObject that match, you can do :

```
var solution = objects.Where(x=> ids.Contains(x.id));
```

With this instead, you'll get a `List<T>` where `T` is an Anonymous type with 2 properties, `Id` that is the string that work as "key" in this specific case, and `Obj`,  a list of `MyObject` which id correspond to the Id property.

```
var solution = ids.Select(x=>new{ Id = x, Obj=objects.Where(y=>y.id == x).ToList()})
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if there is any object in the intersection (which was what I was looking for)

Based on this

```
var a = from o in objects
        join i in ids on o.id equals i
        select o;
```

You can do this as well

```
var isEmpty = objects.Any(x => ids.Any(y => y == x.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct. However, if someone doesn't like using SQL style LINQ, here is the LINQ extension method approach to solving the same problem.

```
var filteredObjects = objects.Join(ids, obj => obj.Id, id => id, (obj, _) => obj);
```

We are joining two different types, so the 2nd & 3rd Join parameter signify that join will be made on id.

The fourth parameter is used to select an object out of the resultant (obj, id) pair after applying join.