# Azure Table Storage equivalent of SQL "IN"

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

In SQL Server I can execute a query like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ProductId IN (1, 24, 9224)
```

How can I do the same with Azure Table Storage? If an `IN`-type operator isn't supported, what is the standard way to retrieve a subset of data (say 100 records out of 1,000,000) based on non-contiguous ID values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Unfortunately, Table Storage does not support `IN` or other `Contains` type query operators.

Please see [Query Operators Supported for the Table Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135725.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that article :/. If you have any experience with table storage would you know of a typical way of dealing with this problem?

Comment: While Brendan is correct that `IN` clause is not natively supported but you could achieve the same using `OR` query. Something like `(ProductId eq 1) or (ProductId eq 24) or (ProductId eq 9224)`. Be careful about possible table scans though if you're not using `PartitionKey` in your queries. HTH.

Comment: Important to note that OR queries often cause table scans, even when you also have a primary key. Better to fire off multiple queries in parallel.

Comment: @Frans this is good to know. That is in part what I was after -- whether there was a best practice (which in this case appears to be firing off multiple requests). Thanks.

Comment: "Note that no more than 15 discrete comparisons are permitted within a $filter string" according to this article [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#supported-comparison-operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#supported-comparison-operators)

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with same thing and i found a workaround. Hope it might help others.
We can use join to acheive this requirement.

```
var a = from prods in products
        join pId in productIds on prods.productId equals pId
        select prods;
```

Got this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602688/intersect-two-collections-which-contain-different-types)